# OPC Server DA and HDA

Tags: server, opc, opc-da

I was asked to provide either the OPC DA ProgID or OPC HDA ProgID.
How do I know if my OPC Server is OPC DA and/or HDA Capable? where do I look for these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is in the server's documentation.

You can also install the server and then use OPC DA / HDA client to browse for servers on the computer, and check if you see it in the list. This will also typically show the ProgID.

You can also install the server and then inspect the Windows registry. There are entries for component categories. OPC Specifications tells you what are the categories (CATIDs) for OPC DA or HDA servers (plus the categories have descriptive names). The entries for the server will be under the respective category, if the server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are two types of OPC OPC DA(Data Access) and OPC HDA (Historical Data Access)
When you want to communicate OPC. if you want to catch the Data from the DCS system then you must have OPC DA. or you want to run in simulation mode then Install OPC as server on your system.

Historical Data Access is used for History values and OPC DA is used for Live values.

Prog ID:- You can find the prog-id from your OPC Setting.it is depend on companies which product you are using.Please check below some examples of prog- id.
Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6
Matrikon.OPC.Simulations.1
OPCSystems.NET.1
EEI.OPCSimulator

you can used OPC Expert for searching a OPC Server in your network.
```